# TextureBrush Causes Memory Leak, Even If I Dispose It

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, gdi+

I am working on a circular menu application.

Before I use a bitmap as background, I must crop it as a circle.

Well, I found a code snippet for cropping the picture [C# crop circle in a image or bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734710/c-sharp-crop-circle-in-a-image-or-bitmap) or:

```
public System.Drawing.Image x(string sourceFile, int circleUpperLeftX, int circleUpperLeftY, int circleDiameter)
{
    Bitmap SourceImage = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(sourceFile));
    Rectangle CropRect = new Rectangle(circleUpperLeftX, circleUpperLeftY, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
    Bitmap CroppedImage = SourceImage.Clone(CropRect, SourceImage.PixelFormat);
    TextureBrush TB = new TextureBrush(CroppedImage);
    Bitmap FinalImage = new Bitmap(circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
    Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(FinalImage);
    G.FillEllipse(TB, 0, 0, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
    return FinalImage;
}
```

But the code causes memory leak after a while in line 6.

Well, I tried adding TB.Dispose(); to prevent it but, that didn't help.

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "causes a memory leak"?  It's pretty hard to genuinely *leak* memory in .net.  (You'd basically have to be writing a container class or holding on to lots of static references.)  And who told you it was line 6 that did it?

Comment: Have you tried a using() block around it?

Comment: Is this method called by some other method in which you have empty try catch block so it swallows exception and it doesn't get disposed?

Comment: There is no try block in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Solved It.

As you said, textbrush is not causing the memory leak.

I used to use this code:

```
pictureBox1.Image = menu.Draw(bos, new Point(Cursor.Position.X - Left, Cursor.Position.Y - Top), (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(sabit).TotalMilliseconds / 4);
```

When I used this, I mean Disposing PictureBox's Image before assigning a new Bitmap to it prevented the memory leak.

```
Bitmap result = menu.Draw(bos, new Point(Cursor.Position.X - Left, Cursor.Position.Y - Top), (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(sabit).TotalMilliseconds / 4);
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = (Image)result.Clone();
        result.Dispose();
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You need to dispose everything that implements `IDispose`, and looking at your code, it looks like:

`SourceImage`, `CroppedImage`, `TB`, `G`

`FinalImage` does not get disposed in this function since it is getting returned, but whatever is using `FinalImage` has the responsibility to dispose of it.

As PowerRoy mentioned, using blocks will take of the disposing for you.

Here is a refactored example using multiple using blocks:

```
public Image CreateFinalImage(string sourceFile, int circleUpperLeftX, int circleUpperLeftY, int circleDiameter) {
  Bitmap finalImage = new Bitmap(circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
  Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(circleUpperLeftX, circleUpperLeftY, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);

  using (Bitmap sourceImage = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(sourceFile)))
  using (Bitmap croppedImage = sourceImage.Clone(cropRect, sourceImage.PixelFormat))
  using (TextureBrush tb = new TextureBrush(croppedImage))
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(finalImage)) {
    g.FillEllipse(tb, 0, 0, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
  }

  return finalImage;
}
```

Comment: +1, And a easy solution is to this by wrapping these things in 'using' statements

Comment: Still causes memory leak. Memory usage increases about 50 mb a second.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR More important is the GDI Object count.  From Task Manager - Processes, View - Select Columns, check GDI Objects, watch your program while you invalidate it (minimize it, move it around, scroll it, etc).

Comment: @LarsTech Well, GDI Object count is stable (33).

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Your memory problem is somewhere else.  Increasing 50 mb a second is pretty dramatic.  I assume it keeps going until you hit an out of memory exception?  cHao's comment is relevant: what makes you point to line 6 in your code as a problem (it's not actually).

Answer (score 0):

Hm... that appears to be a very inefficient way of clipping a bitmap. Here's how I'd do it:

```
public Image x(string sourceFile, int circleUpperLeftX, int circleUpperLeftY, int circleDiameter) {
    using(Bitmap sourceImage = new Bitmap(sourceFile), GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath()) {
        Bitmap destImage = new Bitmap(circleDiameter, circleDiameter, sourceImage.PixelFormat);

        p.AddEllipse(circleUpperLeftX, circleUpperLeftY, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);

        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(destImage)) {
            g.SetClip(p);
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(sourceImage, 0, 0);
        }

        return destImage;
    }
}
```

Right now, the reason for your memory leak is probably forgetting to dispose all those temporary `Bitmap`s. This method only creates two bitmaps and makes sure to dispose one of them, along with the `Graphics` object and the `GraphicsPath` used to create the mask.