# Creating different brush patterns in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to make something similar to paint. I'm trying to figure out how make different brush styles. Like in Paint 3D you get a certain line fills when using the pen tool vs using the paint brush tool.

[image]

I have no idea where to even start. I've spent a good portion of the day looking through documentations, and watching YouTube videos. I'm more lost than when I started. The closest thing I came across was line caps, but that's definitely not what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-fill-a-shape-with-an-image-texture

Comment: Do have a look at my update, which abandons the idea of TextureBrush altogether..

Comment: one of [those](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+floodfill) may help for filling with solid colors..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

!!See the UPDATE below!!

<del>[Hans' link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.texturebrush(v=vs.110).aspx) should point you in the right direction, namely toward [TextureBrushes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.texturebrush(v=vs.110).aspx).</del>

To help you further here a few points to observe:

- <del>TextureBrush is a brush, not a pen. So you can't follow a path, like the mouse movements to draw along that curve. Instead, you need to find an area to fill with the brush.</del>
- <del>This also implies that</del> you need to decide how and when to trigger the drawing; basic options are by time and/or by distance. Usually, the user can set parameters for these often called 'flow' and 'distance'..
- <del>Instead of filling a simple shape and drawing many of those,  you can keep adding the shapes to a [GraphicsPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx) and fill that path.</del>
- <del>To create a TextureBrush</del>  you need a pattern file that has transparency. You can either make some or download them from the web where loads of them are around, many for free.
- Most are in the Photoshop Brush format 'abr'; if they are not too recent (<=CS5) you can use [abrMate](http://www.texturemate.com/abrMate) to convert them to png files.
- You can load a set of brushes to an ImageList, set up for large enough size (max 256x256) and 32bpp to allow alpha.
- Most patterns are black with alpha, so if you want color you need to create a colored version of the current brush image (maybe using a ColorMatrix).
- You may also want to change its transparency (best also with the ColorMatrix).
- And you will want to change the size to the current brush size.

---

**Update**

After doing a few tests I have to retract the original assumption that a TextureBrush is a suitable tool for drawing with textured tips.

It is OK for filling areas, but for drawing free-hand style it will not work properly. There are several reasons..:

- one is that the TextureBrush will always **tile** the pattern in some way, flipped or not and this will always look like you are revealing one big underlying pattern instead of piling paint with several strokes.
- Another is that finding the area to fill is rather problematic.
- Also, tips may or may not be square but unless you fill with a rectangle there will be gaps.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105910/fill-texture-brush-using-image-not-tile/40112000?s=4|28.3185#40112000) for an example of what you **don't** want at work.

The solution is really simple and much of the above still applies:

- What you do is pretty much regular drawing but in the end, you do a `DrawImage` with the prepared 'brush' pattern.

Regular drawing involves:

- A `List<List<Point>> curves` that hold all the finished mouse paths
- A `List<Point> curentCurve` for the current path

In the `Paint` event you draw all the curves and, if it has any points, also the current path.

For drawing with a pattern, it is necessary to also know **when** to draw **which** pattern version.

If we make sure not to leak them we can cache the brush patterns..:

```
Bitmap brushPattern = null;
List<Tuple<Bitmap,List<Point>>> curves = new List<Tuple<Bitmap,List<Point>>>();
Tuple<Bitmap, List<Point>> curCurve = null;
```

This is a simple/simplistic caching method. For better efficiency you could use a  `Dictionary<string, Bitmap>` with a naming scheme that produces a string from the pattern index, size, color, alpha and maybe a rotation angle; this way each pattern would be stored only once.

Here is an example at work:

[image]

A few notes:

In the MouseDown we create a new current curve:

```
curCurve = new Tuple<Bitmap, List<Point>>(brushPattern, new List<Point>());
curCurve.Item2.Add(e.Location);
```

In the MouseUp I add the current curve to the curves list:

```
 curves.Add(new Tuple<Bitmap, List<Point>>(curCurve.Item1, curCurve.Item2.ToList()));
```

Since we want to clear the current curve, we need to copy its points list; this is achieved by the `ToList()` call!

In the MouseMove we simply add a new point to it:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    curCurve.Item2.Add(e.Location);
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

The Paint goes over all curves including the current one:

```
for (int c = 0; c < curves.Count; c++)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-curves[c].Item1.Width / 2, -curves[c].Item1.Height / 2);
    foreach (var p in curves[c].Item2)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(curves[c].Item1, p);
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
}
if (curCurve != null && curCurve.Item2.Count > 0)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-curCurve.Item1.Width / 2, -curCurve.Item1.Height / 2);

    foreach (var p in curCurve.Item2)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(curCurve.Item1, p);
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
}
```

It makes sure the patterns are drawn centered.

The ListView is set to SmallIcons and its SmallImageList points to a smaller copy of the original ImageList.

It is important to make the Panel [Doublebuffered!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185298/update-datagridview-very-frequently/44188565#44188565) to avoid flicker!

---

**Update:** Instead of a `Panel`, which is a `Container` control and not really meant to draw onto you can use a `Picturebox` or a `Label` (with `Autosize=false`); both have the `DoubleBuffered` property turned on out of the box and support drawing better than `Panels` do.

Btw: The above quick and dirty example has only 200 (uncommented) lines. Adding brush rotation, preview, a stepping distance, a save button and implementing the brushes cache takes it to 300 lines.

Comment: oh damn that's niftier than texture brushes!

Comment: @TaW Sorry, I didn't get the part with the ColorMatrix. I scrolled through the doc. of [`QBrush`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html) but I couldn't find anything related. This arised in a follow-up question [SO: QPainter how draw texture with special color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51940533/7478597). I would be happy if you could elaborate this a bit (to enlight us).

Comment: A ColorMatrix is a quick and simple way to change images. See [here](https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide/) for a great guide. - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526858/c-sharp-color-an-image-with-shadows/51533537?s=1|42.5328#51533537) for more coloring an image it. - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749869/picturebox-slider-control-transparency/44758640?s=4|28.6410#44758640) for more on changing alpha (ie transparency.

Comment: @TaW , hello! Can you provide source codes of this project? I was try to reproduce, but it's very ugly. As I understand, you make this example for WinForms? I need an WPF version, but if you don't have wpf, please, give your winForms full example? Update your answer with URL (source code), please?