# QPainter how draw texture with special color

Tags: qt, drawing, textures

I have some patterns which are black with alpha and have some points that I want to draw line with patterns.

I find QBrush can be constructed by texture, but I don't know how to draw it with difference colors.

This answer show a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298313/7117846) in C# code, but I don't know how to change patterns color with ColorMatrix.

Comment: I scrolled through the doc. of [`QBrush`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html) but there was nothing mentioned like a color matrix. There is [`QBrush::setMatrix()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#setMatrix) which is about local brush transformation (i.e. concerning coordinates but not colors). However, it's a [`QPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) which is used in [`QBrush::setTexture()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#setTexture). So, you may make a copy and modify it according to your needs, can't you.

Comment: In case that I missed something (I'm still a learner as well), you may ask the author of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298313/7117846) to elaborate this color matrix idea. Even if he provides the sample in C#, you may notify me and I would be glad to help (out of curiosity). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I have not enough reputation to add a comment in his answer...so I ask this question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider. Have it done by myself: [Comment for Creating different brush patterns in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290951/creating-different-brush-patterns-in-c-sharp/49298313#comment90839954_49298313)

Comment: @Scheff thanks, i see his newest comment, and scrolled through the doc. of Qt graphics , it seems that have not such `ColorMatrix` and `ImageAttributes` class in QT.

Comment: This approach with color matrix is awesome. I will have a look into Qt doc. again. May be, something is available what I missed until now. If not - with the description, I might be able to add something which can change the contents of `QImage` or `QPixmap`. Unfortunately, I've to do some work I'm paid for. ;-) So, it may take some hours until I can provide an answer...

Comment: Thinking twice, my first comment was not that bad. I believe it will become something like: Convert original `QPixmap` with color matrix to a modified `QPixmap`. Use modified `QPixmap` for `QBrush`. (Instead of `QPixmap`, a `QImage` can be used as well.)

Comment: @Scheff I think we can get `QImage` pixel of each point, and then for each multiply with custom 5x5 matrix, put it back to image.

Comment: This is actually what I intend to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modification of RGBA values of an image using a 5×5 color matrix reminds me to the transformation of [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) how it is often used in computer graphics. If you imagine the RGBA values as 4-dimensional color/alpha space the transformation of colors using transformation matrices doesn't sound that revolutionary. (Not that you got me wrong – this impressed me much, and I couldn't resist to try this out immediately.) Hence, I didn't wonder why a 5×5 matrix is needed though there are only 4 color components. (E.g. if a translation of color values is intended the 5th dimension cames into play.)

I must admit that I first applied my knowledge from Computer Animation to this problem and compared my approach to the one described on MSDN [Using a Color Matrix to Transform a Single Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-using-a-color-matrix-to-transform-a-single-color-use) afterwards. Then I realized that the original paper uses transposed vectors and matrices compared to mine. This is just mathematics as

(*v*<sup>T</sup> **M**<sup>T</sup>)<sup>T</sup> = *v'* = **M** *v*

if I remember right.

Practically, it means I have to use matrix rows as columns when I try to reproduce the samples of e.g. the [ColorMatrix Guide](https://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide/). (This feels somehow right to me as it is exactly as we describe transformations in 3d space i.e. translation is the last column of the transformation matrix.)

[image: Snapshot of colorMatrix program]

The sample code:

`colorMatrix.h`:

```
#ifndef COLOR_MATRIX_H
#define COLOR_MATRIX_H

#include <algorithm>

struct ColorMatrix {
  float values[5][5];
  ColorMatrix() { }
  ColorMatrix(const float(&values)[25])
  {
    std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), (float*)this->values);
  }
  float (&operator[](unsigned i))[5] { return values[i]; }
  const float(&operator[](unsigned i) const)[5] { return values[i]; }
};

struct ColorVector {
  float values[5];
  ColorVector(const float(&values)[5])
  {
    std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), (float*)this->values);
  }
  float& operator[](size_t i) { return values[i]; }
  const float& operator[](size_t i) const { return values[i]; }
};

#endif // COLOR_MATRIX_H
```

`colorMatrix.cc`:

```
#include <algorithm>

#include <QtWidgets>

#include "colorMatrix.h"
#include "QColorMatrixView.h"

ColorVector operator*(const ColorMatrix &m, const ColorVector &v)
{
  return ColorVector({
    m[0][0] * v[0] + m[0][1] * v[1] + m[0][2] * v[2] + m[0][3] * v[3] + m[0][4] * v[4],
    m[1][0] * v[0] + m[1][1] * v[1] + m[1][2] * v[2] + m[1][3] * v[3] + m[1][4] * v[4],
    m[2][0] * v[0] + m[2][1] * v[1] + m[2][2] * v[2] + m[2][3] * v[3] + m[2][4] * v[4],
    m[3][0] * v[0] + m[3][1] * v[1] + m[3][2] * v[2] + m[3][3] * v[3] + m[3][4] * v[4],
    m[4][0] * v[0] + m[4][1] * v[1] + m[4][2] * v[2] + m[4][3] * v[3] + m[4][4] * v[4]
  });
}

const ColorMatrix Identity({
  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
});

template <typename T>
T clamp(T value, T min, T max)
{
  return value < min ? min
    : value > max ? max
    : value;
}

QRgb transform(const ColorMatrix &mat, const QRgb &color)
{
  ColorVector vec({
    qRed(color) / 255.0f, qGreen(color) / 255.0f, qBlue(color) / 255.0f, qAlpha(color) / 255.0f, 1.0f });
  vec = mat * vec;
  if (vec[4] != 0.0f) {
    vec[0] /= vec[4]; vec[1] /= vec[4]; vec[2] /= vec[4]; vec[3] /= vec[4]; // vec[4] = 1.0f;
  }
  return qRgba(
    clamp<int>(255 * vec[0], 0, 255),
    clamp<int>(255 * vec[1], 0, 255),
    clamp<int>(255 * vec[2], 0, 255),
    clamp<int>(255 * vec[3], 0, 255));
}

QImage transform(const ColorMatrix &mat, const QImage &qImg)
{
  const int w = qImg.width(), h = qImg.height();
  QImage qImgDst(w, h, qImg.format());
  for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y) for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
    qImgDst.setPixel(x, y, transform(mat, qImg.pixel(x, y)));
  }
  return qImgDst;
}

QImage open(QWidget *pQParent)
{
  return QImage(
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(pQParent,
      QString::fromUtf8("Open Image File"),
      QString()));
}

void update(
  QLabel &qLblViewResult,
  const QColorMatrixView &qEditColMat, const QLabel &qLblViewOrig)
{
  ColorMatrix colMat = qEditColMat.values();
  const QPixmap *pQPixmap = qLblViewOrig.pixmap();
  const QImage qImg = pQPixmap ? pQPixmap->toImage() : QImage();
  qLblViewResult.setPixmap(
    QPixmap::fromImage(transform(colMat, qImg)));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWin;
  qWin.setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Qt Color Matrix Demo"));
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  QVBoxLayout qVBoxColMat;
  QLabel qLblColMat(QString::fromUtf8("Color Matrix:"));
  qVBoxColMat.addWidget(&qLblColMat, 0);
  QColorMatrixView qEditColMat;
  qEditColMat.setValues(Identity);
  qVBoxColMat.addWidget(&qEditColMat);
  QPushButton qBtnReset(QString::fromUtf8("Identity"));
  qVBoxColMat.addWidget(&qBtnReset);
  QPushButton qBtnGray(QString::fromUtf8("Grayscale"));
  qVBoxColMat.addWidget(&qBtnGray);
  qVBoxColMat.addStretch(1);
  qGrid.addLayout(&qVBoxColMat, 0, 0, 2, 1);
  QLabel qLblX(QString::fromUtf8(" \xc3\x97 "));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblX, 0, 1);
  QLabel qLblViewOrig;
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblViewOrig, 0, 2);
  QPushButton qBtnLoad(QString::fromUtf8("Open..."));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qBtnLoad, 1, 2);
  QLabel qLblEq(QString::fromUtf8(" = "));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblEq, 0, 3);
  QLabel qLblViewResult;
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblViewResult, 0, 4);
  qWin.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qEditColMat, &QColorMatrixView::editingFinished,
    [&]() { update(qLblViewResult, qEditColMat, qLblViewOrig); });
  QObject::connect(&qBtnReset, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&]() {
      qEditColMat.setValues(Identity);
      update(qLblViewResult, qEditColMat, qLblViewOrig);
    });
  QObject::connect(&qBtnGray, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&]() {
      qEditColMat.setValues(ColorMatrix({
        0.33f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.33f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.33f, 0.59f, 0.11f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 0.0f, 1.0f
      }));
      update(qLblViewResult, qEditColMat, qLblViewOrig);
    });
  QObject::connect(&qBtnLoad, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&]() {
      qLblViewOrig.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(open(&qBtnLoad)));
      update(qLblViewResult, qEditColMat, qLblViewOrig);
    });
  // initial contents
  {
    QImage qImg("colorMatrixDefault.jpg");
    qLblViewOrig.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImg));
    update(qLblViewResult, qEditColMat, qLblViewOrig);
  }
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

`QColorMatrixView.h`:

```
#ifndef Q_COLOR_MATRIX_VIEW_H
#define Q_COLOR_MATRIX_VIEW_H

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QWidget>

#include "colorMatrix.h"

class QColorMatrixView: public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  private:
    QGridLayout _qGrid;
    QLineEdit _qEdit[5][5];
  signals:
    void editingFinished();
  public:
    QColorMatrixView(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr);
    virtual ~QColorMatrixView() = default;
    QColorMatrixView(const QColorMatrixView&) = delete;
    QColorMatrixView& operator=(const QColorMatrixView&) = delete;
    ColorMatrix values() const;
    void setValues(const ColorMatrix &mat);
};

#endif // Q_COLOR_MATRIX_VIEW_H
```

`QColorMatrixView.cc`:

```
#include "QColorMatrixView.h"

QColorMatrixView::QColorMatrixView(QWidget *pQParent):
  QWidget(pQParent)
{
  QFontMetrics qFontMetrics(font());
  const int w = qFontMetrics.boundingRect(QString("-000.000")).width() + 10;
  for (int r = 0; r < 5; ++r) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; ++c) {
      QLineEdit &qEdit = _qEdit[r][c];
      _qGrid.addWidget(&qEdit, r, c);
      qEdit.setFixedWidth(w);
      QObject::connect(&qEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished,
        [this, r, c]() {
        _qEdit[r][c].setText(
          QString::number(_qEdit[r][c].text().toFloat(), 'f', 3));
        editingFinished();
      });
    }
  }
  setLayout(&_qGrid);
}

ColorMatrix QColorMatrixView::values() const
{
  ColorMatrix mat;
  for (int r = 0; r < 5; ++r) for (int c = 0; c < 5; ++c) {
    mat[r][c] = _qEdit[r][c].text().toFloat();
  }
  return mat;
}

void QColorMatrixView::setValues(const ColorMatrix &mat)
{
  for (int r = 0; r < 5; ++r) for (int c = 0; c < 5; ++c) {
    _qEdit[r][c].setText(QString::number(mat[r][c], 'f', 3));
  }
}
```

`moc_colorMatrix.cc` (to consider moc generated sources):

```
#include "moc_QColorMatrixView.cpp"
```

`colorMatrix.pro` (the qmake project file):

```
SOURCES = colorMatrix.cc QColorMatrixView.cc
HEADERS = colorMatrix.h QColorMatrixView.h
SOURCES += moc_colorMatrix.cc
MOC_DIR = .

QT += widgets
```

and the default sample image `colorMatrixDefault.jpg` if no (cat) photo file is at hand:

[image: Moritz the cat]

Although, I've developed and tested the application in VS2013, I built and tested also on [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) to ensure that the qmake project is complete and self-standing:

```
$ qmake-qt5 colorMatrix.pro

$ make

$ ./colorMatrix
```

---

An enhanced version of this sample code can be found on github [**Qt Color Matrix Demo**](https://github.com/scheff173/ColorMatrix).

[image: Snapshot of Enhanced Demo on github]

Comment: @Shun I've extended the sample a bit and stored it on github. The link is added to the end of my answer (in case you're interested).