# winform label with halo or glow effect on text

Tags: c#, winforms, label

The following method is part of a winform label inherited class. The goal is to make a halo or glow effect on text. So far the effect is actually an outline. Its worth keeping as its not bad but its not there yet.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.Text.Length == 0) return;

  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
  e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
  Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X + Padding.Left,
                                ClientRectangle.Y + Padding.Top,
                                ClientRectangle.Width - (Padding.Left + Padding.Right),
                                ClientRectangle.Height - (Padding.Top + Padding.Bottom));
  StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
  {
    Alignment = TextAlign == ContentAlignment.TopLeft || TextAlign == ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft || TextAlign == ContentAlignment.BottomLeft
    ? StringAlignment.Near
    : TextAlign == ContentAlignment.TopCenter || TextAlign == ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter || TextAlign == ContentAlignment.BottomCenter
    ? StringAlignment.Center
    : StringAlignment.Far
  };

  if ((haloSize < 1) | (haloColor == Color.Transparent))
  {
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, rc, fmt);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
    using (var halopen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(this.haloColor), haloSize) { LineJoin = LineJoin.Round })
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
    {
      if (fmt.Alignment == StringAlignment.Center) rc.X += rc.Width / 2;
      if (fmt.Alignment == StringAlignment.Far) rc.X += rc.Width;
      path.AddString(Text, Font.FontFamily, (int)Font.Style, rc.Height, rc.Location, fmt);
      //path.AddString(Text, Font.FontFamily, (int)Font.Style, rc.Height, rc, fmt);
      e.Graphics.DrawPath(halopen, path);
      e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
    }
  }
}
```

Two questions.

1. Why does the line that is commented out using `AddString` with a `Rectangle` not work but it does work with a `Point`?
2. The halo glow effect can be done with progressively smaller brush size and color change but that feels like inventing a new wheel.  Is there an easy way to do this or an open source library with this already?

Comment: Setting the `StringAlignment`, you don't need to calculate the bounding rectangle: DrawString + StringFormat provide the alignment. `rc` is `this.ClientRectangle`. The Padding value is already included. If the `Text.Lenght + 2 * Pen.Size > rc.Width`, you need to decide what to do: clip the Text or inflate the Label's Size (generating a sort of AutoSize effect). You need to redefine the `Pen` and `SolidBrush`, using a semi-transparent Color. `path.AddString()` is using the wrong `em` size: don't use `rc.Height` as this measure. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074638/7444103) about it.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this: [Creating different brush patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298313/7444103), if you want to add a *special look* to the *glowing* aspect.

Answer (score 0):

1. The original addstring was too big for the box. I think it canceled the draw because it was clipping.
2. Multi-pass works and makes a gradient but it may not be fast enough to add a flicker effect in the glow.

The glow/halo effect provides good contrast for a background image that happens to match the text primary color. This is mostly on target but it does nothing for text that is too long for the label. I might add that later.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.Text.Length == 0) return;

      e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
      e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
      e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
      Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X + Padding.Left,
                                    ClientRectangle.Y + Padding.Top,
                                    ClientRectangle.Width - (Padding.Left + Padding.Right),
                                    ClientRectangle.Height - (Padding.Top + Padding.Bottom));
      StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
      {
        Alignment = TextAlign == ContentAlignment.TopLeft || TextAlign == ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft || TextAlign == ContentAlignment.BottomLeft
        ? StringAlignment.Near
        : TextAlign == ContentAlignment.TopCenter || TextAlign == ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter || TextAlign == ContentAlignment.BottomCenter
        ? StringAlignment.Center
        : StringAlignment.Far
      };
      float EmSize = rc.Height * 0.70f //Font.SizeInPoints  disreguard fontsize and fit height of label
                     * (Font.FontFamily.GetCellAscent(Font.Style) + Font.FontFamily.GetCellDescent(Font.Style))
                     / Font.FontFamily.GetEmHeight(Font.Style);
      using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
      using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
      {
        path.AddString(Text, Font.FontFamily, (int)Font.Style, EmSize, rc, fmt);
        if ((haloSize > 0) & (haloColor != Color.Transparent))
        {
          using (var halopen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255 / (int)haloSize, haloColor)), haloSize) { LineJoin = LineJoin.Round })
          {
            for (int i = (int)haloSize; i > 0; --i)
            {
              halopen.Width = i;
              e.Graphics.DrawPath(halopen, path);
            }
          }
        }
        e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
      }
    }
```