# Fading canvas line in winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms

So what I'm trying to figure out is a way to program this fading line on mouse down for my c# winform paint app (like in the sample picture), but I haven't found any possible way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas for this one? thanks!

[image: Sample]
[image: Sample 2]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to programming.

Comment: You could collect the points in the mousemove event maybe in a timer tick and then use a changing number of brushes or pens, maybe with decreasing opacity to draw each segment. - What is best will depend on what you want: A dynamic, live line or just the effect afterwards.

Comment: When I think of it, there may be artifacts when overlaying semitransparent strokes with a width > 1. Maybe fading to white would be easier, but obviously not quite correct.. - This may be a bit hard for beginners.

Comment: You may want to study [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290951/creating-different-brush-patterns-in-c-sharp/49298313#49298313) which is not using drawcurve but DrawImage. With a suitable list of fading images it should work by  using a time index to create the fade..

Comment: There's nothing built in for this. You'll have to implement the effect entirely on your own via a timer to repeatedly invalidate the control window and your own draw commands in the control's OnPaint.