# How to draw a line over image C#

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]I have a PictureBox which display an image and I want to draw some lines on this image like this , and save it after the drawing , How can I achieve that ?

Comment: "I want to draw some line" Is a very big scope. You need to define exactly how you want to draw lines? From codes or with some tools like MS paint?

Comment: Study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337825/picturebox-paintevent-with-other-method/27341797#27341797) - For a more complex solution look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290951/creating-different-brush-patterns-in-c-sharp/49298313#49298313)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use [Graphics.FromImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). I.e.

1. Create a new bitmap
2. Create a graphics object
3. Draw the original image
4. Draw your line(s)
5. Dispose graphics
6. Save bitmap
7. optionally replace the image in the pictureBox

If you want realtime feedback you might want to create your own PictureBox derived class and override OnPaint to show the lines. And only create a bitmap when you want to save.

Comment: I tried that , I loaded my photo and display it in the picture box , then draw some lines using
graphics = picBox.CreateGraphics();
and some mouse Event method But when I get the image from the picBox it was the same no changes and no lines ... Can U help me with that ?

Comment: @SARADAR21 do not use `.CreateGraphics`. Either draw on a bitmap with GraphicsFromImage, override OnPaint, or attach an eventhandler to the Paint-event.