# How to show image in a circle shape using C++ builder?

Tags: image, c++builder, firemonkey

I just want to show images in circle shapes (I use XE8). I tried TCircle. But the only problem I am facing at now is

*) I am having graphics issue (edges are not smooth as it should be), specially when I make the size of `TCircle` 200px or more.

If I show an already cropped image (in circle shape), it looks much smoother. So I thought, it would be a good idea to crop an image first, then save it as as png image, and then show it on a `TImage`. If I get solution on `TCircle` it would be much easier for me, than croping an image. I would appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.

Comment: If you want to do edge antialiasing in a run-time i would suggest to use GDI+. Surely it would be more expensive than loading pre-processed images.GDI+ supports ARGB pixel format, with alpha channel. Example how to set AntiAliasing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t6sa8s9(v=vs.110).aspx,  here is how to use TextureBrush to draw filled circle - it uses bitmap as a brush and fills circle with that brush - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734710/c-sharp-crop-circle-in-a-image-or-bitmap. So with AntiAliasing mode above you should archive smooth edges.

Comment: GDI+ supports ARGB pixel format, with alpha channel - i mean with proper code you can save the result as a PNG image suitable for displaying on any background. Probably you need to use 2 brush fills -  first fill with semi transparency and 2nd fill a bit smaller (2-4 pixels smaller radius) with no transparency.

Comment: Right now I am handling this issue by a simple technique. I am using an `TCircle`, and set the image as background which I want to crop, then save the screenshot as .png file. Thereafter I am showing this .png image in an `TImage`. By the way, I really appreciate that, you've spend time to give suggestion on my problem @Flanker .